# Why use "IT" when there is nothing that "IT" could be referring to in the preceeding sentence? --- "I don't think it truly did."

Tags: grammar, meaning, meaning-in-context

This is from a conversation on a TV show where they talk about how to tell your children if you are dignosed with cancer. [ITV-how to tell about your cancer diagnosis to family](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Yt0u9jN98XU) (see:0:30 - 0:50)

**TV presenter - What was that moment like for you and how did you process it to then tell your children?**

**The cancer patient - I don't think it truly did.**

I didn't understand why the patient said **"it"**. What does that **"it"** refer to?

Comment: It does sound like 'it', but I think she actually means to say "I don't think **I** truly did [process it]."

Comment: I also think so: sloppy speech, a slip of tongue, a grammar or semantic error, using 'it' where it 'I' would make sense. 'it' would refer to 'moment' which doesn't 'do' anything in the prior sentence, and the 'how did you process' fits with "I didn't' or the softer version the 'I don't think I truly did".

Comment: I hear "I don't think *I* truly did".  The dipthong [aI] is closer to "eh" (no off-glide) but I hear no  dental of the [t] in "it".

Comment: "I don't think **I** truly did" in other words the *former* cancer patient  did not process the diagnosis because, as she explains later, denial can be a mechanism to protect yourself from the shock and fear.

Comment: Possibly meaning "I don't think it (the situation) truly did (get procesed by me)"